# Accessing other cell views from the same table within a NSTableCellView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nsview

At the moment I have an NSTableView that's pretty modest, it has a single column and is populated with some custom cell views.

However each of these cells has a custom radio button subview. It's a child of NSView and they each have a boolean that says wether they're selected or not.

The problem is that I can't find a reliable way of deselecting the other radio button subviews in the other cell views  whenever one is pressed. At the moment I am currently just using

```
[NSApp delegate];
```

to access a function within my app delegate, which in turns gets the cell views from the table view using

```
[self.tableView viewAtColumn: row: makeIfNecessary];
```

Are there any better alternatives to access these sibling cell views?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to update them all would be just to call `reloadData` on the table view after updating your models (changing your flags and whatnot). This way, you just let the table view update whatever it needs to on its own without worrying about which cells are visible and which cells aren't.

Comment: Sorry I worded the question poorly, the table updates correctly when models update, the problem lies in updating the models. Specifically, how updating another row's NSTableCellViews from within a NSTableCellView